# MongoDB: state should be: w is an Integer

Tags: java, mongodb, rest, microservices

I am trying to write a REST web service to get an Object of MongoClient.
 My Rest web service looks like:

```
@SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked", "deprecation" })
    @RequestMapping(path = "/testMongo", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @ResponseBody
    public MongoClient testCredentials(@RequestBody MongoConnect mongoConnect) {

    LOGGER.info("MongoController:: testCredentials()::start");

    String ipAddress = "";
    Integer port = 0;
    String username = "";
    String password = "";
    String result = "";
    MongoClient mongo = null;
    MongoCredential mongoCredential = null;
    String dbName = "admin";
    MongoConnectResponse mongoConnectResponse = new MongoConnectResponse();

    try {
        if (mongoConnect != null) {
            ipAddress = mongoConnect.getIpAddress();
            port = mongoConnect.getPort();
            username = mongoConnect.getUsername();
            password = mongoConnect.getPassword();

            if ((username == null || username.equalsIgnoreCase(MongoConstants.EMPTY_STRING))
                    && (password == null || password.equalsIgnoreCase(MongoConstants.EMPTY_STRING))) {
                mongo = new MongoClient(ipAddress, port);

            } else {
                mongoCredential = MongoCredential.createScramSha1Credential(username, dbName,
                        password.toCharArray());
                mongo = new MongoClient(new ServerAddress(ipAddress, port), Arrays.asList(mongoCredential));
            }

            DB db = mongo.getDB(dbName);
            db.getCollectionNames();

            result = MongoConstants.SUCCESS;


        } else {
            result = MongoConstants.INVALID_REQUEST;
        }

        LOGGER.info("MongoController:: testCredentials()::end");

    } catch (Throwable e) {

        if (e.getMessage().contains(MongoConstants.AUTHENTICATION_FAILED)) {
            result = MongoConstants.AUTHENTICATION_FAILED;
        } else if (e.getMessage().contains(MongoConstants.NOT_AUTHORIZED)) {
            result = MongoConstants.USERNAME_PWD_REQD;
        } else if (e.getMessage().contains(MongoConstants.TIMED_OUT)) {
            result = MongoConstants.NO_SERVER_FOUND + ipAddress + MongoConstants.PORT + port;
        } else {
            result = e.getMessage() + MongoConstants.CAUSE + e.getLocalizedMessage();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        LOGGER.info("MongoController:: testCredentials()::end");
    } 


    return mongo;

    //}

}
```

However, when I am trying to test it through Postman, I am getting the following response:

> {
>       "timestamp": 1508136268005,
>       "status": 500,
>       "error": "Internal Server Error",
>       "exception": "org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException",
>       "message": "Could not write content: state should be: w is an Integer (through reference chain: com.mongodb.MongoClient[\"writeConcern\"]->com.mongodb.WriteConcern[\"w\"]); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: state should be: w is an Integer (through reference chain: com.mongodb.MongoClient[\"writeConcern\"]->com.mongodb.WriteConcern[\"w\"])",
>       "path": "/testMongo"
>   }

Kindly Help.

Comment: I'm just guessing here but do you by any chance have a "w:" in your username or password?

Comment: @dnickless, The username is "admin" and password is "password"

Comment: Sounds like a driver incompatibility issue: https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO-1317 try updating all you libraries to matching versions!